# mediaplayer fadein

Tags: java, android

In my app I've an instance of sound and I like add the fadein. I try with this code but audio is always to max volume.

```
float volume = 1;
float speed = 0.05f;

}
public void FadeIn(float deltaTime)
{
    MediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
    volume += speed * deltaTime

}
```

Comment: What is the example value of `deltaTime`?

Answer (score 0):

Try initiate the media volume to 0.